# Using kate editor to format paragraphs

Tags: format, kate

I'm runnng Kubuntu 18.04.How can I use the **kate** editor to format a text file into paragraphs?  The paragraphs I now have are ragged; I want to fill  out the lines so that they don't exceed a particular length.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for 'justification' (where both text borders are even and consistent). That's not a function of a plain text editor, like Kate. If you use a word processor, then you can justify it. There's left and right justification, and then there's just justification. That's text formatting beyond what's normally seen in plain text editors as it requires higher level formatting such as in .odf, .pdf, .doc, docx, etc...

Comment: I'm looking for left justification. I've done it in the past using Emacs and several other text editors.  My problem is that I haven't needed it for a number of years and I have forgotten what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean static word wrap. To configure it go to Settings → Configure Kate, in Editor Component open Editing, then on General tab set Static Word Wrap to the following values:

- [x] Enable static word wrap
- [x] Show static word wrap counter (if applicable)
- Wrap words to 80 characters

To get something like shown below:

[image: Lorem Impsum]

Temporarily hitting Tools → Apply Word Wrap may get text better too.