# How to edit a text file to a maximum line length with kate

Tags: kate, editing

I have a text file and I want to edit it using **kate**. I want all lines to have a length less than 70 characters but wrapped around so that each line is as long as possible.   This isn't quite word wrapping since short lines must be filled out with more words if possible.  Another way to describe it is that we start with an empty paragraph and append words to it until the length would exceed 70 characters; at that point we start a new line.

How can I do that using kate?

**kate** is not the right tool,even with static word wrap activated. since it won't combine short lines.

Comment: 1.) So you want to destroy paragraphs by merging the entire text back into a single paragraph? 2.) Could the feature you are looking for be called "joining lines"?

Comment: I assume paragraphs are separated by blank lines.  Ypu're right - joining lines would be a good name for it.  But I guess it  still doesn't exist.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1325405/66509 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool for that: `fmt` "simple optimal text formatter". See `man fmt`.